# Bootstrap 4 : How to fix my items to take all the space even those with less content?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have smooth cards on my blog...
I successfully got all  at the same height with flex-fill property but now i want the content div taking all the space and flex-fill is not working for that one...

At least i would like to have all  links to the bottom of the div...

```
<div class="row bg-light"> 
<?php
foreach ($newsList as $news){?>
<div class="col-md-4 d-flex">
  <article class="blogpost border rounded flex-fill">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img src="/images/<?=$news['image'] ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="content h-100">
        <h2 class="itemrecent1"><?= $news['titre'] ?></h2>
        <p class="float-left m-0"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>  <?= $news['dateAjout']->format('Y-m-d') ?></p><br>
        <p class="itemrecent1"><?= nl2br($news['contenu']) ?></p>
        <?php
        if ($category === 'news'){?>
        <div class="itemrecent1"><a href="/news/<?php echo $generator->generate($news['titre']); ?>_<?= $news['id'] ?>" class="btn btnD1">Read</a></div>
        <?php
        }else {?>
        <div class="itemrecent1"><a href="/guide/<?= $category ?>/<?php echo $generator->generate($news['titre']); ?>_<?= $news['id'] ?>" class="btn btnD1">Read</a></div>
        <?php
        }?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
  </article>
</div>
<?php } ?>   <!-- End of news -->
</div>
```

You can look the problem here:

https://cryptoranger.net/news

Thanks :)

Comment: well fixed adding some height in pixels on the title div but if you have a better solution i take it ;)

Comment: Personally I would add a position absolute to the links at the bottom of the divs. Something like position: absolute; bottom:15px; that will keep the links in the same place. You would still keep the min-height attribute you have already applied. Add the positioning code to the itemrecent1 div.

Comment: problem is the content div is not taking all the space left if there is less text...